# Finding a closed form for a simple product

Tags: closed-form, products

I am trying to find a closed form for the following expression:

$$
\prod_{k=1}^{l} \left( 2^kn + 2^k -1 \right),
$$

where $n$ is a positive integer. I know that it is simple to find an expression for the similar product (without the "$-1$"):

$$
\prod_{k=1}^{l} \left( 2^kn + 2^k \right) = 2^{\frac{k(1+k)}{2}}(1+n)^k,
$$

however I am unable to find such a closed form for the first product. Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that it remains simple ? And why do you keep two $2^k$ factors apart ?

Comment: Well, after spending some time on it, I'm less and less inclided to say it is...

Comment: EDIT: I mistyped a $\times$ for a "+", ... sorry

Comment: You should rewrite your formula by noting that $2^kn+2^k=2^km$, to simplify a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth, here are the first few polynomials:

$$2n+1$$

$$8n^2+10n+3$$

$$64n^3+136n^2+94n+21$$

$$1024n^4+3136n^3+3544n^2+1746n+315$$

$$32768n^5+132096n^4+210624n^3+165736n^2+64206n+9765$$

The leading coefficient is of course $2$ raised to a triangular number, and the constant coefficient is the product of the powers of two minus one, which doesn't seem to have a closed-form. There is no reason that the other coefficients be any simpler.